# is there a way to associate a spotify access token to a ASP.NET identity user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, spotify

I'm working on a multilanguage project for accademic purpose. I've written a simple Python Client that make requests to an API server written in ASP.NET. The server retrives spotify info about users. The server interacts with a DB filled by a Golang server that only makes scraping on API's exposed from Spotify. I'm aware that it's a misuse and there are better solutions

Clearly, Golang server, in order to make requests to Spotify API's, needs to know the access token returned from spotify Authorization Code Flow. Overlooking about spotify token expire time, the idea is: after user authentication through Identity module of ASP.NET server (using JWT token), associate the access token obtained calling https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token to user's informations. So, i expose an API in ASP.NET server like this

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("token")]
    public async Task<ContentResult> getTokenAsync(string? code = null)
    {
        //to retrive information about who is the user that making call -> need later for associate spotifytoken
        string accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler t = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();            
        var token = t.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
        var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(token.Subject).Result;
        
        string s = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";            
        if (code == null)
        {     
            var qb = new QueryBuilder();
            qb.Add("response_type", "code");
            qb.Add("client_id", _config["SpotiSetting:clientId"]);
            qb.Add("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email user-library-read");
            qb.Add("redirect_uri", _config["SpotiSetting:redirectUser"]);
            qb.Add("show_dialog", "true");
            return new ContentResult
            {
                ContentType = "text/html",
                Content = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/" + qb.ToQueryString().ToString()
                //Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Result)
            };
        } else
        {               
            //if i'm here, api is the callback designed for spotify
            var qb = new QueryBuilder();
            qb.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            qb.Add("code", code);
            qb.Add("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44345/spotify/token");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, s);
            req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(qb);
            req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "here_my_secret_encoded_CLIENTID:CLIENT_SECRET");
            var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            AccessToken json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(result);

            user.spotifyInformation.authToken = code;
            user.spotifyInformation.accessToken = json;
            var res = _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            if (res.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Content("ok");

            }
            else
            {
                Content("Problem");
            }
            
        } return Content("");
    }
```

The problem is that the second time that API is invoked, it's spotify that is sending the first authorization token (needed to request access_token), so I lost user information retrived in the first request. Should be better write two distinct API and separate callback from user request?

It's my first question here, so please to have mercy

Comment: Rather than roll-your-own implementation, you should use an authentication provider to handle login with Spotify using the ASP.NET Authentication features. It will save you development time. Here's an example provider you could use of which I'm one of the maintainers: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify/

Comment: Thank you very much, but in this case i should have separate authentication between API server and Spotify. The original idea was connect different social media/resourse (like, spotify, twitter and so on) to the server and use the client as a usage/recommendation monitor, so login with a specific provider don't really solve the problem of link a user account to generic platform account